# I'm trying to use pip to install pyinstaller but it's giving me this error: ImportError: No module named 'bz2'

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, importerror

I reinstalled all python versions I have (2.7, 3.4 and 3.6) and I'm not getting the 'encodings" error anymore, but another problem took it's place.

I'm trying to install pyinstaller, I run
`pip install pyinstaller` but it gives me:

```
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.2.1.tar.bz2
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1641, in bz2open
      import bz2
  ImportError: No module named 'bz2'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 355, in prepare_files
      do_download, session=self.session,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 782, in unpack_url
      session,
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 671, in unpack_http_url
      unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 654, in unpack_file
      untar_file(filename, location)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 583, in untar_file
      tar = tarfile.open(filename, mode)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1566, in open
      return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tarfile.py", line 1643, in bz2open
      raise CompressionError("bz2 module is not available")
  tarfile.CompressionError: bz2 module is not available
```

Comment: Can you include more details? How exactly are you using `pip`? Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: I'm trying to install pyinstaller. I solved the other problem but it's still not working, the error now is: importError: No module named 'bz2'. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score -1):

open the directory of python and make sure that the scripts folder there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MndBq.png)